# C# - Event that fires when a list is not empty

Tags: c#, events

Hey, I'm currently creating a program where I have several lists of information. When the entries in list 1 is processed, they'll be removed from list 1 and added to list 2. When the entries in list 2 is processed, they'll be removed and added to list 3 and so forth. When a list is processed, all the items present when the processing started will be removed from the list. Entries will be added to all the lists continuously as long as the program is running, and in no predictable manner. New entries will have to be processed fairly fast.

I figured that the best way to achieve this is to have each list fire an event whenever something is added and execute an Action. To make my life easier I created a custom list class that takes an Action as a constructor parameter, and invoke that Action whenever the event is fired (see code). However, the way I implemented it, where the event is fired when something is added to the list, is horridy inefficient with many new entries in a short timespan.

So basically I'm wondering if it's possible to create an events that fires whenever a list is not empty. In addition, is there any good way to assure that an event won't fire again as long as it has already been fired and is still "active" (in lack of a better explaination).

If anything is unclear, say so, and I'll try to clarify. Thanks!

```
    public class EventDrivenList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private Action action_on_list_change;
        private delegate void ListChangedDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
        private event ListChangedDelegate ListChangedEvent;

        private List<T> unprocessed_items; 
        public List<T> List
        {
            get
            {
                lock (unprocessed_items)
                {
                    return unprocessed_items;
                }
            }
        }

        public EventDrivenList(Action action, int size)
        {
            action_on_list_change = action;
            unprocessed_items = new List<T>(size);
            ListChangedEvent += new ListChangedDelegate(OnChangeMethod); 
        }

        public EventDrivenList(Action action)
        {
            action_on_list_change = action;
            unprocessed_items = new List<T>();
            ListChangedEvent += new ListChangedDelegate(OnChangeMethod); 
        }

        ~EventDrivenList()
        {
            ListChangedEvent -= new ListChangedDelegate(OnChangeMethod);
        }

        private void OnChange(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListChangedEvent != null)
                ListChangedEvent(this, e);
        }

        private void OnChangeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
             action_on_list_change.Invoke();            
        }

        new public void Add(T item)
        {
            lock (unprocessed_items)
            {
                unprocessed_items.Add(item);
            }
            OnChange(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        new public void Remove(T item)
        {
            lock (unprocessed_items)
            {
                unprocessed_items.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        new public int Count()
        {
            lock (unprocessed_items)
            {
                return unprocessed_items.Count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your finalizer, and most of your locks, are useless.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx

Comment: Changed to ArrayList, removed the deconstructor and the useless locks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `ArrayList` is even worse.  Use `Collection<T>`.

Comment: Ouch, well, learning by failing. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your concern about duplicate/overlapping firings, an option: create a handler which "unwires" all handlers while it's handling (and then re-wires them when it's finished handling).

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the ObservableCollection? It has default een CollectionChanged event which fires when there is something changed in the list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx

Comment: Too bad I didn't find that ealier, because that does basically the same thing as I've coded, plus a lot more. Might as well replace most of my code now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, your problem could be solved by using a ManualResetEvent. The event would fire and stay active when an item is added, and items continue to be present in the list (i.e. non-empty). When the list is empty you could simply reset the event...

An ObservableCollection is another option... however this would fire a CollectionChanged event every time an item is added or removed, which would be the same as what you're currently doing manually...